# Missing words when create pdf invoice with chinese character

Tags: invoice, pdf, invoice-pdf

I am currently having a problem:
Currently when I create an invoice in the backend in Chinese, my font is missing some characters that cannot be created. I tried searching for different fonts on google but couldn't find the right one.
So I want to ask that in order to be able to create a pdf file, which font do I need and where do I download it.
[image]
Thank for reading and supporting me

Comment: Please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I've find the right font for my question. If anyone have the same problem with me, you can download the font in this link: 
https://chinesefontdesign.com/classic-song-ti-font.html